# In Rails 5 how to use wicked pdf and mailgun together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attachment, mailgun, wicked-pdf

Using the mailgun API is slightly different from using ActionMailer. 
Often I see something like this:

`attachment['...'] = ...`

in the solutions I found..

but what I am trying to build with mailgun currently looks like this:

```rb
def print
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  @order = @invoice.order
  @customer = @order.customer
  pdf = render_to_string(:pdf       => 'file_name', 
                         :template  => 'invoices/invoice.pdf.erb', 
                         :layout    => 'invoice_pdf.html')



  mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new 'key-xxxxxx'
  mb_object = Mailgun::MessageBuilder.new

  mb_object.add_attachment pdf
  mg_client.send_message 'mg.mydomain.com', mb_object
end
```

And when I press the "print" button in my application (the pdf is meant to be send to a printer), then I get:

**string contains null byte**

(highlight!) `mb_object.add_attachment pdf`

Apparently the `pdf` object is not really something. 
How could this be?

**EDIT 1**

Maybe it's better to ask, since this also needs to be done: How do I save from wicked pdf to S3 (in as few steps as possible).

Comment: A PDF as a string will often contain a null byte. That tells me it's working. [The Mailgun MessageBuilder documentation](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/blob/master/docs/MessageBuilder.md) says `add_attachment` should be a path to the file on disk, not a string in memory. [Here's the relevant line of code](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/blob/master/lib/mailgun/messages/message_builder.rb#L398)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I figured having the files saved somewhere would be best, so all the invoices' pdf's have to go to S3. Thing is, this would use somewhat the same mechanics. Anyway, I'll check the `add_attachment` by using an other random file that I actually do have saved. From wicked pdf to S3 is another one to solve.